# connect to container using ssh after adding new user and installing ssh

Tags: docker, ssh

I am struggling to ssh into a container. After executing 
`docker run -p 22:22 --network=host -it ubuntu:14.04` after `adduser admin` and installing ssh in my ubuntu based image i opened a new docker terminal and fired `ssh username@${hostip}` but connection is refused for my added user. thanks for your help

**Edited**

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:fe:c4:aa:ea
      inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::42:feff:fec4:aaea/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:536573 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:596145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:21717921 (21.7 MB)  TX bytes:945577957 (945.5 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:4e:1a:70
      inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe4e:1a70/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1674522 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:781497 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:1431596796 (1.4 GB)  TX bytes:47605814 (47.6 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:c7:b0:50
      inet addr:192.168.99.106  Bcast:192.168.99.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fec7:b050/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:6326489 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1012444 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:8806794970 (8.8 GB)  TX bytes:1868661107 (1.8 GB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:94 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:94 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
      RX bytes:14064 (14.0 KB)  TX bytes:14064 (14.0 KB)
```

docker ps Output

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED               STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
6851d647642c        ubuntu:14.04        "/bin/bash"         About an hour ago   Up 31 minutes                           stoic_jang
```

Also i installed ssh using `apt-get install ssh` not sure if it's the right package.

Comment: Couple questions... 1) is sshd already running on the docker host? 2) Is sshd enabled in the ubuntu:14.04 image by default?

Comment: I just installed ssh in the docker container. should i install it in the image and in the docker machine too ?

Comment: No, I just suspect the -p 22:22 may be conflicting with port 22 already open on the docker host if it's running sshd.
sshd should be already installed in the container/image.

Comment: What happens if you use `docker run -p 2222:22 --network=host -it ubuntu:14.04` and then do `ssh -p 2222 admin@${hostip}`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual ssh command which you're running that doesn't work, and include any output or error messages that the command produces. Adding `-v`, `-vv`, or `-vvv` to the ssh command will cause it to produce additional debugging output.